# create empty files using touch command from words contained in a test.txt file

Tags: command-line, bash, files

I am trying to write a one line command to create 20 empty files with names extracted from a .txt file in another folder directory with the same txt extension.

I tried

```
for i in $(cat test.txt); do grep -w $i | touch $i.txt ; done
```

and

```
cat test.txt| while read line ; do grep $line ; touch $line.txt ; done
```

as well as

```
for filename in $(cat testfile.txt) ;  do touch head -20 $filename.txt; done
```

It does not work.  I do not know how to specify the 10 first words of the test.txt file.

Comment: How about `for i in $(head test.txt); do touch $i.txt ; done`?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a minimal example of your `test.txt` file - the format matters e.g. whether there is one word per line, multiple words per line etc.

Comment: ...or rather `for i in $(head -n 20 test.txt); do touch $i.txt ; done`, since you want 20 entries.

Comment: @Fred007... you mean 20 first words?

Answer (score 2):

Does this work for you?

```
while IFS= read -r i; do
  touch "$i".txt
done < <(head -20 filename.txt)
```

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted - although I'd suggest replacing the command substitution + here string with a process substitution + redirection i.e. `done < <(head -20 filename.txt)` and adding a `-r` to the read in case any of the filenames contain escapes. Arguably it should be `while IFS= read -r i; do` if we assume that any leading whitespace is intentional. I guess we should wait for clarification from the OP.

Comment: I would use [`while IFS= read -r i`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/209184/201297)

Answer (score 2):

Get first 20 words.

Using [cut](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/cut.1.html):

```
$ for i in $(cut -d ' ' -f1-20 a.txt); do touch $i.txt; done
```

(with [mapfile](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/bash.1.html#shell%20builtin%20commands)):

```
$ mapfile -d ' ' -n 20 -t < a.txt; touch ${MAPFILE[@]/%/.txt}
```

(with [awk](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/gawk.1.html)):

```
$ awk '{for (i=1; i<=20; i++) {system("touch "$i".txt")}}' a.txt
```

(with [shell parameter expansion](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/bash.1.html#expansion)):

```
$ a=($(<a.txt)); a=(${a[@]/%/.txt}); touch ${a[@]:0:19}
```

Answer (score 1):

`xargs` command has `--arg-file` flag, which allows using arguments for a command you intend to run from file. Thus, you can do

```
xargs --arg-file=filenames.txt touch
```

If you want first 20 lines

```
head -n20 filenames.txt | xargs  touch
```

Substitute `tail` instead of `head` for last 20 lines from file

Comment: he wants 20 words.

Comment: @bac0n  That's not been confirmed yet, but I'll edit my answer if that is in fact so